# GetLocaleFormatSettings

Tags: delphi

I own D6, D2009, and D2010. GetLocaleFormatSettings did not exist in D6. From web searches, it appears that GetLocaleFormatSettings was deprecated starting with D-XE2 and replaced by TFormatSettings.Create. I have also inferred from my searches that GetLocaleFormatSettings must have been introduced in D7, but cannot confirm. Can anyone confirm the version in which GetLocaleFormatSettings was introduced and the last version before it was deprecated?

Comment: If you have Delphi 6, then I can confirm you this was introduced in Delphi 7. The rest I can't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I confirm for Delphi 7:

Extract from the French D7 doc:

> Unité
>
> SysUtils
>
> Catégorie
>
> routines de formatage de chaînes
>
> Syntaxe Delphi :
>
> procedure GetLocaleFormatSettings(LCID:Integer;var
>   FormatSettings:TFormatSettings);
>
> Syntaxe C++:
>
> externPACKAGE void __
>   fastcallGetLocaleFormatSettings(intLCID;TFormatSettings&FormatSettings);

For the deprecated, regarding the doc's versions:

This looks like **XE**:

[2010: Not yet](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/SysUtils.GetLocaleFormatSettings)

[XE: Deprecated](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/XE/en/SysUtils.GetLocaleFormatSettings)

Comment: Many thanks. I will use GetLocaleFormatSettings for D7 through D2010 and TformatSettings.create for D-XE onwards.